# bootstraptable data-url attribut unwanted query parameters! :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I Have a Problem using Bootstrap Table.
lets take a look on this example

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/server-side-pagination.html

on the source code you find 
data-url="/examples/bootstrap_table/data"
when you run the example page and take a look what the the GET call is you will see this:

GET http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data?order=asc&offset=0&limit=10

behind data the query parameter:
?order=asc&offset=0&limit=10
its simply not compatible with my api and my api send a clear jason back. :(
i can manage to remove the "offset=0&limit=10" with the attribute
data-pagination="false or dont set it. 
but i ever end up with ?order=asc or ?order=desc when i put the attribute data-sort-order="desc" when i dont set the attribute i end up with query parameter ?order=asc.
iwant remove completly the query parameters and when i need some i set it by myself on the url attribute.
please help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would recommend you to add a fiddle with your minified working code.

Comment: i ll do it later, thanks for the tipp.
but the behavior of the bootstrap-table its on every example same take a look at the GET request it ever send this ?order=asc when the data-url url attribut point to a direct api call (not to a file.json) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-url` is for server-side processing. The server sorts, filters and selects data from a source.

What you might be looking for is `data-ajax`. It just loads all the data and all the processing is done client-side.

UPDATE:

Providing a working example via jsfiddle is not that easy with the given source (cross-server it should be jsonp and SSL is missing) but if it is only about the options in your initialization, i can provide you this:

https://jsfiddle.net/rsacc203/1/

the `data-ajax="your/path"` is missing because the above mentioned situation.

@Updated Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rsacc203/3/

Comment: Thank you, could you provide an example how to call on the data-ajax attribute an URL like
 http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data
or better the js script code i need for that.
my personal json response from server is like:
{"example_1":{"columns":["id","nr","code"],"records":[["1","1","0107SOC"],["2","2","0108AHD"]]}}


or

{"example_2":[{"id":"1","nr":"1","code":"0107SOC"},{"id":"2","nr":"2","code":"0108AHD"}]}


Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the Query Parameters completly.

HTML Attribute:

```
data-query-params="queryParams"
```

JS:

```
function queryParams() {
    return {
    };
```